# How do I programmatically write files to Sharepoint Online via a UNC path?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an ASP.Net website that has functionality allowing users to upload a document and have it pushed into a Sharepoint Document Library. It does not use the .NET client API. It does this simply by writing the file to the Library via a configured UNC path (eg. \domainname@SSL\sharepoint\sites..). In order for this to work there are a few requirements:

- the website must be in an application pool running under the account of a domain user with appropriate permissions
- The WebClient service must be installed and started
- If the domain name is a FQDM (with dots in the name), a registry entry (AuthForwardServerList) must exist with the domain listed (e.g. https://domain.com)

This all works well, and has been used by a few clients to connect to their in-house Sharepoint implementations.

Now I am trying to integrate this functionality with Sharepoint Online for one of my clients. The client is using Active Directory Federation Services to allow Single Sign On for their users.

I have confirmed that:

- The application pool is running under an account that has appropriate permissions
- If I log in to Windows with that account and paste the UNC path into Windows Explorer I see the full folder structure without any prompt for credentials
- The AuthForwardServerList contains 'https://clientname.sharepoint.com'
- The WebClient service is installed and started

I'm not having any luck with this. My website reports that it is unable to access the Document Library. Unfortunately because this is all installed on my client's intranet site, I am unable to to debug the code to see exactly what response I'm getting from Sharepoint.

Can anybody suggest any additional configuration I need to do? Or suggest a way to troubleshoot the problem?